# Font icon fa fa-eye fa-lg is not reflecting or displaying on page

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
  <li style="display : {!IF(editShow == true, '', 'none')};">
    <a class="remove-table-row" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeLeadTime(leadTime.Id)">
      <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Delta
    </a>
  </li>
  <li style="display : {!IF(editShow == true, '', 'none')};">
    <a class="remove-table-row" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeLeadTime(leadTime.Id)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Full Comparison
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `font-awesome` css library to make them work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
  <li style="display : {!IF(editShow == true, '', 'none')};">
    <a class="remove-table-row" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeLeadTime(leadTime.Id)">
      <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Delta
    </a>
  </li>
  <li style="display : {!IF(editShow == true, '', 'none')};">
    <a class="remove-table-row" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeLeadTime(leadTime.Id)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Full Comparison
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Riya should have worked you must be missing something.